# How to apply a custom scrollbar to Google Maps infowindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, custom-scrolling

I have an `infowindow` that uses a vertical scrollbar when the content does not fit in the window. I would like to apply the [jquery custom scrollbar](https://github.com/mzubala/jquery-custom-scrollbar) to the `infowindow` with the thin rounded scrollbar (I think it is the default-skin).

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q47c78st/2/). I have added all the necessary code, but the default scrollbar is still shown.

Loading:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".mapInfoWindow").customScrollbar();
});
```

Adding the skin:

```
content: '<div class="mapInfoWindow modern-skin">'...
```

CSS:

```
.mapInfoWindow {
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

EDIT:
After the answer below, the scrollbar is now cut off at the bottom, see the image below as requested:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` for calling `customScrollbar` and link jQuery Custom Scrollbar css file to your project.

```
setTimeout(
    function()
    {
     $(".mapInfoWindow").customScrollbar();
    }, 3000
);
```

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/q47c78st/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but why does the content disappear?

Comment: Do you notice that the scrollbar is cut off at the bottom when you scroll down?

Comment: @sim1 I don't. give me a screenshot which is shown your problem

Comment: see above in the question I added the screenshot - you will see the border isn't shown and then it scrolls a little past the bottom edge. I have seen it on second the link you provided (in the comments).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I know the infowindow basically only gets created once the marker is clicked the first time - is there any way to call the `$(".mapInfoWindow").customScrollbar ();` once that window is ready? Or is the above the only way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91963/discussion-between-alireza-safian-and-sim1).